# Why is the type of mshtml.htmldocument.body.all is just object?

Tags: microsoft.mshtml

say dw1 is a variable whose type is msthml.htmldocument

dw1.all type is mshtml.ihtmlelementcollection

However, dw1.body.all type is object.

Why is it so?

To be more blunt.

Why is the type of `dw1.all` differs from the type of `dw1.body.all`?

Answer (score 1):

I get the following

[image]

when the DOM loads and resolves, you'll get body.All is an HtmlElementCollection of all elements underneath the current element, as defined at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.all(v=vs.110).aspx

This table will help navigate this structure
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx

All - Gets an instance of [HtmlElementCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelementcollection(v=vs.110).aspx), which stores all [HtmlElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx) objects for the document.

Body - Gets the [HtmlElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx) for the BODY tag.

Here's how you load the DOM

```
        // Construct DOM
        HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument();

        // Obtain the document interface
        IHTMLDocument2 htmlDocument = (IHTMLDocument2)doc;
        string htmlContent = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h2>An unordered HTML list</h2><ul>  <li>Coffee</li>  <li>Tea</li>  <li>Milk</li></ul></body></html>";

        // Load the DOM
        htmlDocument.write(htmlContent);

        // Extract all body elements
        IHTMLElementCollection allBody = htmlDocument.body.all;


        // All page elements including body, head, style, etc 
        IHTMLElementCollection all = htmlDocument.all;

        // Iterate all the elements and display tag names
        foreach (IHTMLElement element in allBody)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element.tagName);
        }
```

Comment: That is not answering the question. Actually what is dynamic in c#

Comment: dynamic in c# simply means object in vb.net. You simply said doc.body.all is of type dynamic and I am asking why it is object/dynamic

Comment: Jim I add a code example to load the DOM, this should clear it up for you.

Comment: Why is the type of `dw1.all` differs from the type of `dw1.body.all`?

Comment: // All elements
            IHTMLElementCollection all = htmlDocument.all;
        
            For me, they are both of type IHTMLElementCollection